# Asp.net session expire very soon

Tags: asp.net, session

I get this message too often and think that it is not usual, how i can fix this issue?

> *A worker process with process id of '8052' serving application pool 'mywebsite.com' has requested a recycle because it reached its private
>   bytes memory limit.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this is not an expire because of a timeout, it's an application pool recycle due to memory limit. Usually very bad.

if you have full control of your ASP.NET application I suggest you profile it carefully and detect where you are allocating and not releasing / disposing a lot of memory.

It might help to understand what are the common use cases users are going through more often and start investigating those.

Are you loading a lot of byte[] in memory for file downloads?

are yoou keeping too many references in the Session?

once we had a similar problem and we found out only after several weeks that we were storing a reference to pages in the Session so all visited pages were kept in memory all the times. Not easy to find but once we corrected this the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot Davide Piras for your fast and complete response

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a memory leak. There are many possible causes, possibly session or request instances registered with static events. Operations that are trying to load too much data into memory, session timeouts set too long etc.

You need to do some profiling to identify the cause.

Of course its also possible you just don't enough memory for the number of users and need to scale, but it's highly unlikely unless you have a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application use a lot of memory? Regarding to [this post](http://jesperen.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/understanding-aspnet-memory/) you have reached allowed memory size for application and IIS restarts the application pool.