# Session is not getting cleared

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-timeout

I have a solution with multiple projects and 2 webapps in it. One webapp is related to asp.net website and the other one is related to MVC.

I opened a webpage one from asp.net site & other from MVC website.

Both the projects is having same timeout and similar code in global.asax.

Now there is a JS code in both the websites and every session timeout+1minute a regular call happens to the backend server to check session status.

In asp.net pages session is getting expired but in mvc site session still exists.

Comment: where do you store your session ? inproc/outproc ?

Comment: How do you check that the session exists?

Comment: It's inProc session. And Session ID we are passing on every request Via Cookie. I could see the Request in browsers DEV tool having same session ID

Comment: What is the backend in asp.net pages? which page type? aspx? and the question should be reversed? Session is getting cleared?

Comment: One project is having all aspx pages and within it session is getting expired as per session timeout configured in that project. But in other MVC project session is not at all getting expired. Every thing is in one solution deployed under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Set same timeout settings for both in **web.config**

```
<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

follow links for more understanding which i have mentioned below:

[Asp.net Session Expire soon on live Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311649/asp-net-session-expire-soon-on-live-web-server)
[Asp.net session expire very soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279862/asp-net-session-expire-very-soon)